# how can i get the text inside an anchor tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

```
<div id="div1">
<a herf="#">link1</a>
<a href="#">link2</a>
</div>

//jquery
$("#div1 a").click(function(){
var text = $("#div1 a").text();
});
```

on the above tags i want to get text in side an anchor tag which i clicked on it
but clicking on each of above anchor tag gives me a same answer ('link1link2'), how can i get 'link1' when i click on first a tag and get 'link2' when i click on second anchor tag,
be aware that anchor tags can be infinite

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
  $("#div1 a").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside the click handler, `this` refers to the element which triggered the handler execution :

```
$("#div1 a").click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```