# Put text value into input from ajax live search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I found this [AJAX Live Search PHP](http://ninetofive.me/blog/build-a-live-search-with-ajax-php-and-mysql#comments), and works fine, this is the [Live Preview](http://ninetofive.me/data/tutorials/live-search/) but I want instead open new window just put the text of clicked element into the searched box, after I modified the search.php I put a link into H3  like this:

```
$html .= '<h3><a">nameString</a></h3>';
```

and I been trying this but nothing:

```
 $('ul#results li h3 a').click(function(e) {
 var ciudad = $(e.target).text(); 
  $("#search").val( ciudad );
});
```

Hope you can help me, thanks !

Solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('ul#results li h3').live("click",function(){
var ciudad = $(this).text();
$("#search").val( ciudad );
});
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, because you aren't showing much code:

```
$('ul#results li h3 a').click(function(e) {
    var ciudad = $(this).text(); 
    $("#search").val( ciudad );
});
```

They key is this selector: `$('ul#results li h3 a')` -- that *has* to be the exact HTML enveloping the clicked-on text.

Use Chrome DevTools (i.e. F12) to view the highlighted text and verify that that is the correct DOM location.

Reference:

Assuming that your code is correct and the clicked-on text is encompassed inside an anchor tag, see:

[how can i get the text inside an anchor tag in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823065/how-can-i-get-the-text-inside-an-anchor-tag-in-jquery)

Comment: I'm already try that and don't works. The code is in the first link. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Then the selector is incorrect. You must correctly identify the selector, or post a screen shot of the the F12 window showing a "found" result to be copy/pasted into the `#search` element. You can also add `alert(ciudad);` (after var cuidad=etc) to help you identify when you've found the correct selector.

Comment: The selector is ok, I find the solution just change `.live("click",function(){` instead `.click(function(e) {` I edited my post with the solution. Thanks.