# Get link's text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have  a simple link:

```
<a class="myid">Myid Text</a>
```

Whenever the link is click, I want to retrieve "Myid Text" by displaying it in a java script. How will I do that? Below is my initial javascript code:

```
$(".myid").click(function (event) {                
    alert("Display link's text here..!!");
});
```

Comment: How is `myid_print_table_id_link` related to `myid`? `$('.myid').text()`

Comment: atleast do some research before asking

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/kocgzarb/

Comment: See https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ and https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/. If you are new to jQuery I really recommend to go through the tutorial.

Comment: @Satpal --> Typo, I already edited it. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if here (in SO) is allowed to give lmgtfy-links, so I'll just give you a hint - google `get element's content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".myid").click(function (event) { 
    // I want to prevent the elements default action (thanks @ Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy). 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0sg94gxu/).

Read more about preventDefault [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

Comment: You might suggest using `preventDefault for` OP at this context.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `.text()` in jquery.

```
$(this).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.link').click(
     function()
     {
        alert($(this).text());
         }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Linkkk</a>
```

Probably your class name is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery:

```
$(".myid").click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant believe there are still questions like this.

But here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823065/how-can-i-get-the-text-inside-an-anchor-tag-in-jquery)